# Java FX 3D: Objects not respecting their Z coordinate

Tags: java, 3d, javafx-8

I'm trying to animate a sphere orbiting another sphere however the sphere in front doesn't move behind the second when it's Z coordinate is made less.

e.g (0,0,1) and (0,0,-1) both appear in front of (0,0,0) Just their sizes are different based on the perspective. Not sure how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong, new to Java FX!

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;

    Planet earth = new Planet("Earth",50,0,0,0);
    Planet earth2 = new Planet("Earth 2",50,25,0,50);

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll(earth,earth2);
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        camera.setNearClip(0);
        camera.setFarClip(1000);
        camera.setTranslateX(-WIDTH/2);
        camera.setTranslateY(-HEIGHT/2);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);

        primaryStage.setTitle("3D Scene");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        timeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void timeline(){
        final long start = System.nanoTime();
        double FACTOR = 1;
        new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                double t = (now-start)/1000000000.0;
                //System.out.println(t);
                //earth2.setTranslateX(150*Math.cos(t));
                earth2.setTranslateZ(150+500*Math.sin(t));
                earth.setPosition(0,0,0);
                System.out.println(earth2+" | "+earth);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

```
public class Planet extends Sphere {

    private String name;

    public Planet(String name, double radius, double x, double y, double z){
        super(radius);
        setPosition(x,y,z);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPosition(double x, double y, double z){
        setTranslateX(x);
        setTranslateY(y);
        setTranslateZ(z);
    }

    public void move(double x, double y, double z){
        translateXProperty().add(x);
        translateYProperty().add(y);
        translateZProperty().add(z);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+name+"] - ("+getTranslateX()+","+getTranslateY()+","+getTranslateZ()+")";
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You need to create the `Scene` with depth buffering enabled—[`Scene#<init>(Parent,double,double,boolean,SceneAntialiasing)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing)).

Comment: Lovely! That worked, I also had to set the NearClip to 0.01 instead of 0 also and now it works! edit: if you make that an actual answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable depth buffering on the `Scene` containing the 3D objects and/or transforms. Here's [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html):

> An application may request depth buffer support or scene anti-aliasing support at the creation of a `Scene`. A scene with only 2D shapes and without any 3D transforms does not need a depth buffer nor scene anti-aliasing support. A scene containing 3D shapes or 2D shapes with 3D transforms may use depth buffer support for proper depth sorted rendering; to avoid depth fighting (also known as Z fighting), disable depth testing on 2D shapes that have no 3D transforms. See `depthTest` for more information. A scene with 3D shapes may enable scene anti-aliasing to improve its rendering quality.
>
> The depthBuffer and antiAliasing flags are conditional features. With the respective default values of: false and `SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED`. See `ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D` for more information.

Depth buffering cannot be enabled after the `Scene` has been instantiated, you must use one of the following constructors:

- [`Scene(Parent,double,double,boolean)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean))
- [`Scene(Parent,double,double,boolean,SceneAntialiasing)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing))

The `boolean` argument is the depth buffering flag.

***Note:** This also applies to [`SubScene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html).*

---

You also mentioned you had to set [`Camera#nearClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Camera.html#nearClipProperty) to `0.01` instead of `0`. For convenience, here's the documentation of that property:

> Specifies the distance from the eye of the near clipping plane of this `Camera` in the eye coordinate space. Objects closer to the eye than `nearClip` are not drawn. `nearClip` is specified as a value greater than zero. A value less than or equal to zero is treated as a very small positive number.
>
> **Default value:**
>      `0.1`

It says the value should be greater than zero. Of course, it also says a value `<= 0` will be treated as a "*very small positive number*", which I understand to mean a value `<= 0` will be interpreted as a number arbitrarily close to, *but still greater than*, zero. So I'm not exactly sure why setting the value to `0` would cause any problems.